# How do you combine Passport.js social login with JWT?

Tags: node.js, jwt, passport.js, passport-facebook

I used this tutorial to implement local, Facebook, Twitter, and Google login strategies: https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-facebook

Then read this one about JWT: https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens

The first tutorial seems to use sessions. My question is how do you combine the two e.g. a Facebook login that spits back a JWT (if that is even the correct thing to do)?

Also, is this the same thing as "Bearer" token? Ultimately what I am trying to do is client passes `Authorization: Bearer ab123ncoiwuencr` (http://dev.apollodata.com/react/auth.html#Header) that was granted by the server with local and social logins and the server validates it. I'm confused whether JWT is the right approach.

Comment: It's possible, but you have to serialize/deserialize users outside of passport and disable session in passport and handle this by yourself. I wrote a tutorial a while back, might help: https://blog.hyphe.me/token-based-authentication-with-node/

Comment: @JohannesMerz Thanks! What you wrote makes sense. I'll give a shot. So in `Authorization: Bearer <mytoken>`,  a "bearer token" is really just a JWT? Is this considered "OAuth 2.0" or is there more to it? Your tutorial seems to be all I really need to work with http://dev.apollodata.com/react/auth.html#Header, so I'm wondering why people do OAuth 2.0 and OpenID.